# How to model this code line in react js:-

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

```
       <image src ='https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data={this.state.link} &amp;size=300x300'/>
```

It inputs dynamic link to url and gives out dynamic qr code.
I am new comer in react-js please help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are trying to set a prop with an expression, the syntax for that is `<image src={\`https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=${this.state.link} &amp;size=300x300\`}/>`

Answer (score 0):

if `this.state.link` is dynamic value? then you can format code like below.

```
<image src ={`https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=${this.state.link}&amp;size=300x300`}/>
```